# jQuery - GET News.html 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

For some reason, this doesn't work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "News.html",
    cache: false,
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#content").load(data);
});
```

It gives me:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/News.html 404 (Not Found)
```

But for whatever reason, opening that url manually **(copy paste the url) works** just fine.
And i thought it had something to do with browser cache at first so i added the `cache: false` option to the ajax function but even then.. argh..

Also it does **not** show up as a requested URL in my `access.log` file..

For information i guess, i'm running:

- lighttpd
- php as fast-cgi via localhost:port
- mapped .html => .php
- Running OpenBSD 5.3

and uncommented (in `/etc/php.ini`):

- cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

Also:

```
# ls *.html
News.html     index.html
```

And here's the request headers for `News.html`:

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1/News.html
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

### Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:127.0.0.1
Referer:http://127.0.0.1/index.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

### Response Headers

```
Content-type:text/html
Date:Tue, 16 Jul 2013 21:55:05 GMT
Server:lighttpd/1.4.32
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.21
```

## Checkpoint

Conclusion from the comments so far is that this might not be a jQuery issue at all.
Considering that the server responds with all the data (i've checked raw data sent) and it contains everything, but the response **header** says `404`.

Meaning, the data is found but the header says 404... it's odd to say the least..

## curl test

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1/News.html' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Host: 127.0.0.1' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://127.0.0.1/' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' --compressed
Here you'll soon find a facebook feed, among other things :)
```

## Zerkms test

```
# echo "wham bam" > zerkms_doesnt_believe.html
#
```

[image]

## Config files

- [lighttpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/MwayPqXr)
- [php-5.3.ini](http://pastebin.com/FbUYDAZH)

## Error logs and what not

- [lighttpd-error.log](https://gist.github.com/Torxed/6028350)

## cURL test

[image: A cURL copy paste test]

## Manual FastCGI test via a Python client:

```
# python fcgi_app.py  
{'FCGI_MAX_CONNS': '1', 'FCGI_MPXS_CONNS': '0', 'FCGI_MAX_REQS': '1'}
```

After some tinkering, i figured out how the FastCGI protocol works and i found a client that matched my needs, funny enough it matched the name of my script so here's the output:

```
# python fcgi_app.py  
('404 Not Found', [('x-powered-by', 'PHP/5.3.21'), ('content-type', 'text/html')], '<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>test php</title>\n\t</head>\n<body>\nChecking</body>\n</html>', '')
```

And [Here's the source](https://gist.github.com/Torxed/6028715)

Giving me the conclusion that this is in fact a PHP issue (even tho i've hated on lighttpd for not honoring the 200 code php should respond with.. And for that i'm sorry. Should go bash a little on PHP and see if that helps me come to a conclusion)

## Temporary Solution

Placing the following in the top part of your .php page will work around this issue.
Note that it's a clean workaround, it will work but it's not a long term fix for sure.

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.0 200 Found");
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure News.html is written with a uppercase N?

Comment: I'm sure. Again, copy-pasting the link works (with captial N) :)

Comment: Provide all the headers, both request and response. And check additionally that in the Size column it's not `(from cache)` (assuming you're using chrome)

Comment: Since you're mapping `.html` to `.php`, are you sure that your PHP code isn't returning a 404, say if the headers indicate it's an AJAX request?

Comment: Not sure jacob, didn't think php in default mode was clever enough to do any real data analyzation of the headers to distinguish from an Browser AJAX request and a Browser GET request.

Comment: try this: `url: "News.html?anyword",`

Comment: @Akam Funny, i get 404 but the page loads (manually ofc). Chrome web-tools/analyze tools says it's a 404 with the same response headers but i can see the content properly render in the browser o0 If run in AJAX as `url: "News.html?anyword",` it also gives 404 but doesn't render anything.

Comment: Try restarting Apache, or opening in another browser

Comment: @Jorge Not helpful, first off.. running `lighttpd`, secondly.. this isn't windows. A restart doesn't fix the issue at hand.

Comment: @zerkms You're on to something for sure. edited with a "checkpoint" to this problem.

Comment: @Torxed: right click on the request on `Network` tab and choose `Copy as cURL`. Now use the console cURL tool and reduce the headers sent step by step to find which one makes it to behave that way.

Comment: So **exactly the same** cURL works fine. I don't believe it :-) Are you sure it's not `(from cache)` in size column? What if you change the `News.html` to something else (that exists)?

Comment: I can record it and post it on youtube :) It works, no exceptions. But manually in a browser it works as well, it's only through AJAX/jQuery that it actually honors the 404 and doesn't render anything. The browser says 404 but shows all the content it could get, so in loose terms it works manually (even despite a 404) but not in AJAX. By changing `News.html` what do you mean into something that exists?

Comment: @Torxed: create `zerkms_doesnt_believe.html` file with some content and request it instead of `News.html`

Comment: @zerkms Most defently something with lighttpd + php in this case, and the way i've mapped `.html` files to be parsed as a `.php` because i want to embedd php code inside the HTML data for number of reasons.. gha..

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas :-S Good luck with that (will put it to read-it-later to check after several days)

Comment: what happens when you delete the News.html and create a new, clean, empty file ? Same error ? (might be a header issue)

Comment: maybe access rights ? maybe another file/application has this file in progress/locked.

Comment: You have done a pretty good job of eliminating the request, agent and transport as the cause.  On the server side, both lighttpd and php have the capability to add headers to the response that will override the default headers.  Can you attach your lighttpd config?

Comment: @Joe sure and done, I'm all out of ideas and the lighttpd team says that "i've configured it to respond with 404" which i haven't, so i feel like i'm left all alone on this one :/ (And no, this has nothing to do with access rights Panique, even tho i appreciate all angles of attack here) :)

Comment: Also added a detailed error log of lighttpd. It says `404` even tho i've specificly told PHP to **always send 200** via `cgi.nph = 1` (recent chage)

Comment: Also added a cURL screenshot showing this annoyingly odd issue. I was considering that this was an PHP issue until `cgi.nph = 1` and now i'm back to blaming lighttpd. But i can't rule anything out because i don't have any proof that PHP responds 200, testing fastcgi manually is my next best thing on the todo list :S

Comment: Wrote and then found another Python fastcgi client which gave me the oportunity to see live data from the FastCGI server that PHP offers, and PHP does indeed send me a 404 even tho the page is loaded.. so now i'll have to go investigate PHP -.-

Comment: Am I missing something? Or have we not yet seen the source of News.html?

Comment: `test.php` == `News.html` (See screenshot, essentially just `<?php print "test"; ?>`

Answer (score 2):

This smells a bit like a same-origin policy issue.
The path you are specifying may be causing the issue.
Try

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/News.html",
    cache: false,
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#content").load(data);
});
```

And let me (us) know if that helps.

Comment: Sorry to say, as the long winded conversation in the question states, this is not a "loading the content" issue per sé, it's the server sending malicious headers to a perfect content. The response when specifying `/News.html` is the same, **"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"**

Answer (score 2):

This one had me stymied for a bit.  Feeling some compulsive urges, I installed lighttpd and php5 on an fresh Ubuntu 12.10 VM (didn't have a BSD one handy).  I had to modify to `poll` from `kqueue`, but other than that I used your lighttpd.conf.  And everything worked fine.

So then I installed your php.ini file, and BAM http status 404 while returning proper content.  So that narrowed it down to php-cgi.

Turns out that when the service started, it would log

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php-5.3/modules/pdo.so' - /usr/local/lib/php-5.3/modules/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

So id did a quick search and changed one line in the php.ini from

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php-5.3/modules"
```

to

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php5/20100525"
```

restarted php-cgi, and voila status 200 to go along with the content.

Comment: This does not help at all, sorry to say. There are no such error messages on my system since i'm running OpenBSD `/user/local/lib/php-5.3/modules` does in fact exsist. And `pdo.so` is not a module on my system so i don't see why it would even load for me?

Comment: The point I was making is that the error presented as you described when php-cgi had an issue, suggesting that is where the trouble originates.  You have php-cgi logging to syslog, if you are not getting any entries there, you could capture the inter-process traffic with `tcpdump -s 1500 -w ~/file.cap -Xi lo0 port 9123` then request the page and examine the capture to determine whether the issue is in the reply from php-cgi or lighttpd's interpretation of it.

Comment: Understood, i got confused tho considering your post describes "debugging" steps which basically just tells me to check my logs, which i have and they were empty (for a number of reasons) and considering php didn't log anything but lighttpd did, i thought it was an lighttpd issue, which it later on turned out not to be. But i'm sure your tip is viable and helpful to anyone besides me so i'll give you a point for it but unfortunately it did'nt help. There is however something wrong with my PHP configuration which i need to straighten out tho so you are right about that..

Answer (score 1):

After setting up a fresh OpenBSD 5.3 server, and installing with your config files, I was able to narrow down the root cause.

In the lighttpd.conf you have `server.chroot = "/var/www/"` so all of its path names exclude the /var/www from the front.  The php-fastcgi process is not chrooted, so it has a slightly different view of the file system.

Solution #1:
Don't chroot lighttpd and change the `server.document-root`, `accesslog.filename`, and `server.errorlog` to absolute paths.

Solution #2:
Use php-fpm or similar to make PHP chroot aware/capable

Comment: That sounds right up my alley of problem solution actually, dno why i didn't think of it myself. I'll give it a go tomorrow!

Answer (score -2):

Use simple **jQuery .load()** method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content").load('News.html');
});
```

Comment: Same issue there, the load() function build on a simple AJAX request in the end and it's not the "fetching data" method that's the issue, it's the return code from the server.

The server sends correct **data** but not correct **headers** which makes jQuery confused..